# Custom typeahead using Solr

Tags: solr

We have a requirement to create typeahead using Solr with following logic:

Let's say my Solr core has a field called jobtitle with two values as "senior software engineer" and "software engineer"

1. Now, if I search for "**sen**", result should be  "**sen**ior software engineer"
2. if I search for "**soft**", result should be in following order:

   "**soft**ware engineer"

   "senior **soft**ware engineer"
3. If I search for "**software eng**",result should be in following order:

   "**software eng**ineer"

   "senior **software eng**ineer"

Is there anyway we can achieve this functionality?

Comment: Did you tried the solr autosuggester?

Comment: Yes but we need to have the custom logic